# sqlite, what is the fastest way to get a row ?

Tags: c++, sqlite

if I want to get the first row, usually I use such query :

```
SELECT * FROM tableOfFamousUndeadPeople  WHERE ID = 1
```

I guess sqlite check ID of all rows then I get the result. So if my table have n rows, the time is O(n).

Actually, my ID column has the flags INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, I don't know if sqlite do some blackmagick trick to speed up. I don't know if there is another way to get one row. I don't really understand how to use ROWID or if my ID column is used as ROWID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time is much better than O(n).  The database stores the primary key (also other indices) sorted, so that it can perform a binary search to find the desired row.

The time complexity is O(log(n))

http://bigocheatsheet.com/

> what is the fastest way to get a row ?

Search using an index (including the primary key) that is highly discriminating.

(A discriminating index is one where many of the values are mostly unique.  Indexing gender is not very good because it divides a table into just two categories, male and female.  Indexing a ZIP code is pretty good for most purposes.  Using the primary key is ideal, since each value is guaranteed to be unique).

Comment: but, m I using the fastest way?

Comment: Yes, if you have the primary key, that is the fastest way to locate a row.